# Magento 2 Show MSRP on Product page

Tags: magento2

I'm trying to work out how to show MSRP on the Product page on **Magento 2**.
I want to only display the "*MSRP*" if the value is great than the "*Price*".

On our current site which is 1.9.2 I have it showing as "`RRP: $100.00`"

In 1.9 I edited `app/design/frontend/theme/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml`

and added

```
<?php if ($_product->getMsrp() > $_product->getPrice()) :?> 
            <?php echo $this->__('RRP: ') ?> <?php echo Mage::helper('core')->currency($_product->getMsrp(),true,false);?>  
            <?php endif;
```

As Magento 2 is completely different I'm having trouble trying to work it out.

Any help would be appreciated

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I have not worked out how to make this work as yet. 

At the moment my work around is to have the MSRP in the PRICE field and my sell price in the SPECIAL PRICE field.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I implemented a simple Magento 2 extension to show the MSRP price on the product listing and product detail pages, without requiring a user to click a link.

See more details here: https://github.com/krakencommerce/magento2-module-display-msrp-inline

Screenshot showing what the extension does:

[image]